# Is there a way to return the Basecamp URL of a Fogbugz case via the Fogbugz API?

Tags: api, fogbugz, basecamp

I am trying to query all Fogbugz cases that contain Basecamp URL's, in order to match these against open Basecamp projects/to-do URL's.

The problem is that the Fogbugz API has no mention of the Basecamp Project URL in it's documentation.  I can return a list of cases that contain Basecamp URL's, but I cannot get to the actual URL's.

```
$search = file_get_contents(FBZ_URL.
    "?cmd=search&token=".
    $token.
    "&q=Basecamp+Project+URL&cols=ixBug,sTicket,sTitle,tags,dtDue");
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 1) Try asking at http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com instead. 2) Is URL stored in some custom field, or is it plugin-added field? Try checking [this answer](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/729) about getting custom fields.